# Change name on the main Stack Exchange profile

Tags: support, stack-exchange, profile-page, display-names, network-profile

I was able to change my name on all Stack Exchange sites, but not on the main profile at http://stackexchange.com itself.

Is there a ways to do the change on http://stackexchange.com as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The central Stack Exchange profile is synchronized with your oldest profile; it'll update automatically.

So, since your first ever Stack Exchange profile was created on Stack Overflow, that's the profile it'll synchronize with.

You can force a manual sync by clicking on the `Sync with oldest profile` link on the right-hand side of your network profile page:

[image: sync link]

That's right underneath the "About Me" section on the right-hand side (empty in your case).

Comment: This worked great for me!

Answer (score 4):

**Same problem still exists today at the time of writing this.**

1. On your Network Profile page, click **Update profile info**

   [image: Update profile info]
2. Select whichever profile you want it to be in sync and hit **copy**

   [image]